# Correct approach when notifying ViewModels of UserControl events in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF View, I'm loading data into User Controls like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ItemEditVm}"  />
```

And then in the ViewModel:

```
private ItemEditViewModel _itemEditVm;
public ItemEditViewModel ItemEditVm
{
    get
    {
        return _itemEditVm;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemEditVm = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ItemEditVm");
    }
}
```

I've got a series of DataTemplates to say which View belongs to which ViewModel. And then in my business logic, I can just spin up a new ViewModel for the UserControl then assign it to the property and all works as expected.

However, to resolve the next task in this application, I need to be able to notify the parent ViewModel of events occurring inside the UserControl. I've done this with a simple event on my child ViewModel and a listener on the parent:

```
public event EventHandler ItemEditViewModelChanged();
```

So when I create my ViewModel I can just add a listener:

```
ItemEditViewModel vm = new ItemEditViewModel(itemId);
vm.ItemEditViewModelChanged += vm_ItemEditViewModelChanged;
```

And do what needs to be done in vm_ItemEditViewModelChanged().

However, I am instinctively uncomfortable with this. While it doesn't violate any MVVM principles direclty (things are still testable, Views and ViewModels are still separate), it doesn't seem a very flexible way of doing things and it does create undesirable logical links between ViewModel classes.

Is there a better way of doing this? Is my approach to creating and loading UserControls into ContentControls a poor way of creating child controls? Or am I worrying over nothing?

Comment: Is your `ContentControl`  placed in a View does have a `ViewModel` ?

Comment: Have you tried using messages or eventaggregator?

Comment: @AbinMathew Yes, it does. That's where I'm raising the event.

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras No, just standard events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to implement things like this with dependency injection. Typically there will be multiple notifications that need to be made, so start by declaring an interface:

```
public interface ICustomEventHandler
{
    void Event1();
    void Event2();
    // .. etc
}
```

Then in the child vm you use dependency injection to inject whatever object needs to watch it:

```
public class ChildVM
{
    [Inject] public ICustomEventHandler Watcher {get; set;}

    // .. etc ..
}
```

First of all this makes mocking very easy, so your unit tests are covered, but more importantly you've formalized the dependencies between this module and the rest of the code and also kept your options open as to how best to implement it. (A simple solution would be for the parent to implement that interface directly and inject itself into the child at creation, in another case you may need to use an intermediate class with singleton scoping or multiple clients).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this work for you but just my thought.

[image]

If you have a `MainViewModel` which holds your all other `ViewModels` like the picture above then you can expose `Properties/Methods` to invoke MainViewModel and Let `MainViewModel` take the decision to talk to a different `ViewModel`.